# Some components blurry on monitor in portrait format on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display

Since recently my right monitor has shown some blurry components. This only happens in portrait orientation (Independent of whether left or right).

Things I tried:

- The driver is up to date
- Scaling is set to 100%
- Played around with clear type (the actual text in the clear type menu is shown perfectly)
- The display resolution is set to the native one
- Tried different Display ports
- Tried setting the monitor as the primary one
- Scaling / resolution settings in Nvidia driver
- Enabled and disabled Windows' fix blurry app feature
- Various other suggestions found here: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/265413/portrait-monitor-orientation-causes-text-blurring/265414) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/252352/why-is-text-blurred-when-i-rotate-the-screen) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/1290082/how-can-i-solve-blurry-text-in-windows-10) [4](https://superuser.com/questions/502400/fonts-in-some-programs-look-blurry-on-a-1920x1080-ips-monitor-in-windows-8) [5](https://superuser.com/questions/265413/portrait-monitor-orientation-causes-text-blurring)

What's weird is that some text (like the entire windows explorer or spotify) are sharp, other text and windows (e.g. Chrome) are blurry. Some cases like windows terminal have sharp text in the tabs but blurry console text.

It's not the panel, it worked before and when I use my Debian machine it doesn't have any issues (plus it can show some components sharp independent of where they are on the screen)

I'm using Windows 10 Pro insider preview Build 21327 and an NVIDIA RTX 2070 Super with driver version 470.05.

[Here's a photo](https://i.imgur.com/BdLj2HE.jpg) of the sharp monitor (left).
I hope it illustrates the blurry bits (right click menu, terminal) and the non-blurry bits (terminal tab, advanced settings) The right click menu text has a "glow".

A screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7g5C.png), the rendering looks good on the screenshot on all windows, in reality chrome has blurry text, the clear type windows has sharp text

Comment: Try the following:  Start, Settings, Display.  Right side window. Select Advanced Scaling Settings.  Enable"Let Windows fix apps so not blurry" . Make sure scaling is one of Window selections and not your own. Close out, restart and test.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotteen to mention that that is also among the things I have tried

Comment: Please provide a screenshot, ideally with both blurry and non-blurry parts.

Comment: Just added a photo, thanks

Comment: It has to be a screenshot to accurately judge the fonts’ subpixel rendering.

Comment: I just added a screenshot, interestingly the issue is not visible on a screenshot

Comment: I’m out of ideas, sorry. The subpixel rendering is incorrect (because the physical pixels are rotated), but it could not cause the glow you see. In your screenshot, there is only one part of text that is not using subpixel rendering: The title “ClearType Text Tuner”.

Comment: Appreciate you taking a look though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this case it must have been the Windows Insider Preview build.
I recently had an update and the issue is fixed without further input from me.